# How to rotate buttons in portrait?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to rotate bootstrap buttons in portrait mode. I tried using `position:absolute` button not succeed.

Here is the fiddle of button

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/creativedev/uevnj130/1/)

See How it looks when rotating:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/creativedev/uevnj130/2/)

**Some points:**

1. No orientation change to rotate so media query on orientation change will not work.
2. Resolution of the screen is dynamic so static width,height,margin top or bottom will not work.
3. Rotation vertically means the vertical view of the button.

Comment: @AndyHolmes: updated

Answer (score 2):

you can use `transform:rotate`

```css
.btnSelection {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-top: 100px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid" id="conditional_div">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 pull-right">
      <div class="btnSelection">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary conditional_playlist">Test</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary conditional_playlist">Test1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary conditional_playlist">Test2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when run your snippet,its same. No rotation.

Comment: because you are in a desktop, therefore the desktop is in `landscape` mode, that's why I added a Screenshot of the Result.

Comment: No,this is not depends on orientation, I just want to rotate button in landscape too.

Comment: you say in your question *"I want to rotate bootstrap buttons in portrait mode. "* So you want to have them rotate in both modes? or you want to rotate like  portrait ?

Comment: means without orientation change

Comment: Not like this, i need vertical buttons, one by one

Comment: They are vertical one by one.. Care to make an image of what you want? It is unclear to me now

Comment: it's not like i want. See example https://jsfiddle.net/creativedev/uevnj130/2/. I just want to see this button within window without static width and height

Comment: but this is static again :(

Comment: Static how? I really can't understand why you mean. Make a draw of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: 100px from top is static. What i want is to get height and set bottom right corner.

Comment: Again make a draw.. This is still unclear to me